# Select a row based on List in column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to select row as below

```
ID   | Name | Course
------------------------------------------------
01   | ABC  | ['Science','Maths','English']
02   | DEF  | ['Social', 'French', 'Computer']
```

Case 1-> I need to fetch the row based on list like below
My List[Science, Java, .Net]

Result should be -->

```
 01   | ABC  | ['Science','Maths','English']
```

since in MyList i have Science in common

Comment: share your entity classes

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal Thanks for the solution, actually im looking for namedQuery like Select o from Student o where o.name='ABC' and o.course=:courseList

where my courseList is a list ['Science','Maths','English']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
    public static Specification<Student> filterPostByTagIdList(List<String> courses) {
        if (courses == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String course : courses){
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("courses").get("name"), course));
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        });
    }
```

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Student> {
}
```

```java
List<String> courses = ...;
@Autowired
StudentRepository studentRepo;

List<Student> students = studentRepo.findAll(filterPostByTagIdList(courses));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually im looking for namedQuery like Select o from Student o where o.name='ABC' and o.course=:courseList where my courseList is a list ['Science','Maths','English']